# Share image from bundle and link on Facebook in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to share image,link etc to Facebook from my iphone app.My app Link,cation,name and description posted successfully. But i can't share image. Please follow my code..

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

self.dictionary =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:     @"https://www.google.com/ios", @"link",
 imgData, @"data",

 @"AppName", @"name",

 @"Testing", @"caption",

 @"say something about this", @"description",
 nil];
```

my share facebook code is..

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed" andParams:dictionary andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

My problem is how to take image from bundle and how to share selected image to Facebook?Please help me..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use like below:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image1" ofType:@"png"];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"My hat image", @"message", data, @"source", nil];

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/photos" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.Your code is working. But i need to use facebook share @"me/feed" . In that case i can't share image to Facebook

Comment: if you want to share images then you have to use me/photos.