# Facebook iOS SDK share picture from App

Tags: ios, facebook, image, sharing

I try share picture to Facebook. This is work.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   kAppId, @"app_id",
                                   url, @"link",
                                  @"http://yandex.st/morda-logo/i/logo.png", @"picture",
                                   title, @"name",
                                   produc, @"caption",
                                   tempString, @"description",
                                   message, @"message",
                                   nil];
```

But I want share picture from my App. I try

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   kAppId, @"app_id",
                                   url, @"link",
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav.png"], @"picture",
                                   title, @"name",
                                   produc, @"caption",
                                   tempString, @"description",
                                   message, @"message",
                                   nil];
```

But I have problem:

> :frame:decisionListener: delegate: 
>   -[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc98b1d0

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much

Comment: [I found answer](http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748140/share-image-from-bundle-and-link-on-facebook-in-iphone)

Comment: what is the solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using "source" and not "picture". Picture is expecting the url string.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   kAppId, @"app_id",
                                   url, @"link",
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav.png"], @"source",
                                   title, @"name",
                                   produc, @"caption",
                                   tempString, @"description",
                                   message, @"message",
                                   nil];
```

Comment: [UIImage length]: unrecognized selector.  Again the same error

Comment: [UIImage length]: unrecognized selector.

Comment: How did you resolve the [UIImage length]: unrecognized selector?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I am not user Facebook gonna decode your bitmap image, save the image on their server and make it available on your wall ^^

Try an URL instead of the NSData data of your image.